# execvpe implicit declaration error

Tags: c

I'm testing the execvpe() in c, I tried the below code, which cause the error as "implicit declaration of function 'execvpe' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //execl("/bin/echo", "echo", "Hello, world", NULL);
    char *path = getenv("PATH");
    char  pathenv[strlen(path) + sizeof("PATH=")];
    sprintf(pathenv, "PATH=%s", path);
    char *envp[] = {pathenv, NULL};
    char *tests[] = {"ls", "-lR", NULL};
    execvpe(tests[0], tests, envp);
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute \"%s\"\n", tests[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I test this code as below to test the existing status (which I copied from [Compiler warnings for execvpe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241835/compiler-warnings-for-execvpe-function), this time no error. Is there anyone can help me to figure out what's wrong in my above code? Thanks!

```
#include <unistd.h>
extern int execvpe(const char *file, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `#define _GNU_SOURCE` directive to before any of the `#include` directives, e.g.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

In Glibc, all of these headers pull in `features.h` which sets various macros based on the setting of `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, `_POSIX_SOURCE`, `_GNU_SOURCE`, etc. At the time of the first include, it is not set. When you get down to `unistd.h`, `features.h` has already been included and won't be applied again.

Comment: Thank you very much! After I move it, it has the error like "error: implicit declaration of function 'execvpe' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    execvpe(tests[0], tests, envp);"

Comment: @coco It works here with GCC 6.3.1 and Glibc 2.25. Are you possibly using some other C standard library that doesn't provide `execvpe`?

Comment: You can see a demonstration of the lack of warnings online here: https://godbolt.org/g/m2eyRi

Comment: I tried your link, didn't find my current gcc version (4.3.1). I use mac, and I brew installed gcc (6.3.0) after I saw your comment, here is the same error:                                                  
`warning: implicit declaration of function 'execvpe' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     execvpe(tests[0], tests, envp);
     ^~~~~~~
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_execvpe", referenced from:
      _main in cc0Bn7X3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: brew? OS X? If so, you can't use `_GNU_SOURCE` . (Well technically you could if you installed and linked with Glibc, but that would be pretty unusual.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to use other functions.